# Discrete approximation to a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution

I'd like to make a discrete approximation to a bivariate normal distribution. That is, I would like to compute a matrix where each entry is the probability of falling into one of the little square of the below picture.

[image]

Here is what I did so far.

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(graphics)

euclide = function(x,y){sqrt(x^2+y^2)}
maxdist = 40
sigma = diag(2)
m = matrix(0,ncol=maxdist*2 + 1, nrow=maxdist*2 + 1)
for (row in -maxdist:maxdist){
    for (col in -maxdist:maxdist){
        if ( euclide(abs(row), abs(col)) < maxdist ){
            lower = c(row-0.5, col-0.5)
            upper = c(row+0.5, col+0.5)
            p = pmvnorm(lower = lower , upper = upper, mean = c(0,0), sigma = sigma)    
        } else {
            p = 0
        }
        m[row + maxdist + 1,col + maxdist + 1] = p
    }
}
m = m[rowSums(m)!=0,colSums(m)!=0]
contour(m, levels = exp(-20:0), xlim=c(0.3,0.7), ylim=c(0.3,0.7))
```

[image]

It works ok. It is quite slow (for large `maxdist`) though and I am hoping to improve its computational time. But this is not my main issue...

The main issue is that with my method, I can't change the number of small squares close to the center to make a better approximation close to the mean. I can only add squares on the surrounding. In other words, I would like to be able to set the variance of both axes of the bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Have you heard of [Tauchen](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0165176586901680)? And generating joint normal variates from `N(0,1)` draws? (e.g., [slide 269-272 here](http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/Teaching706/TimeSeriesSlides.pdf)) Or are you working on this exercise for another particular purpose?

Comment: May I ask for what purpose you want to use the matrix you are constructing?

Comment: It is a dispersal kernel (probability of dispersing to a cell that is at a given distance), with a slightly more complicated set of details as there are subcells within cells. It is computationally faster to simulate individuals present in cells and mating at random than present over a spatial continuum. This is why I wanted this discrete approximation.

Comment: @Remi.b OK, thanks for the info. I wonder if the essential operation is therefore going to be a convolution (of this transition matrix with the distribution over the current state to yield a distribution over the next state). If so, consider computing the convolution via the fast Fourier transform, for greater efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation.  Like @DanielJohnson says you can just use the cdf form univariate normal, but it should be same as using the `pmvnorm`, shown below.  The version using `pnorm` is much faster.

```
## Choose the matrix dimensions
yticks <- xticks <- seq(-3, 3, length=100)
side <- diff(yticks[1:2])  # side length of squares
sigma <- diag(2)               # standard devs. for f2
mu <- c(0,0)                # means

## Using pnorm
f <- Vectorize(function(x, y, side, mu1, mu2, s1, s2)
    diff(pnorm(x+c(-1,1)*side/2, mu1, s1)) * diff(pnorm(y+c(-1,1)*side/2, mu2, s2)),
    vec=c("x", "y"))

## Using pmvnorm
f2 <- Vectorize(function(x, y, side, mu, sigma)
    pmvnorm(lower=c(x,y)-side/2, upper=c(x,y)+side/2, mean=mu, sigma=sigma),
                vec=c("x", "y"))

## get prob. of squares, mu are means, s are standards devs.
mat <- outer(xticks, yticks, f, side=side, mu1=0, mu2=0, s1=1,s2=1)
mat2 <- outer(xticks, yticks, f2, side=side, mu=mu, sigma=sigma)

## test equality
all(abs(mat2-mat) < 1e-11)  # TRUE
all.equal(mat2, mat)        # TRUE

## See how it looks
library(lattice)
persp(mat, col="lightblue", theta=35, phi=35, shade=0.1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an R person, but I'm sure there is a CDF function for the normal distribution. If what you want is literally a matrix of the probability of falling into each square are depicted, we can use this CDF function to get the answer. Since the 2D normal distribution has independent marginal distributions, the question here just amounts to asking the 2 questions for each square described by the axis locations [x_left, x_right] and [y_left, y_right]:

1. Whats the probability of a 1D normal random variable being in the interval [x_left, x_right]?
2. Whats the probability of another, independent 1D normal random variable being in the interval [y_left, y_right]?

Since the two are independent, the full probability for the square is:

```
P = (CDF(x_right) - CDF(x_left))*(CDF(y_right) - CDF(y_left))
```

This is an exact answer, so computational time should not be a problem!

EDIT: I should also say that you can choose a grid with more ticks on each axis close to zero in order get the resolution you desire. The above probability formula for each square still holds.